# Stiefel-Whitney class of an orthogonal representation

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes

Let $BG$ denote the classifying space of a finite group $G$. For which group cohomology classes $c\in H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ does there exist a real vector bundle $E$ over $BG$ such that $w_2(E)=c$?

Comment: You mean $c \in H^2(BG; \mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Comment: Yes. Topological cohomology of BG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put 
$$A=\{c\in H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2): c = w_2(V) \text{ for some } V\}$$
Here are some observations:

1. Let $V$ be a real representation with determinant $L$, so $w_1(V)=w_1(L)$.  Put $W=V\oplus L\oplus L\oplus L$.  We find that $\det(W)=1$ and $w_2(W)=w_2(V)$.  It follows that $A=\{w_2(W):\det(W)=1\}$.  Moreover, if $\det(V)=\det(W)=1$ then $w_2(V\oplus W)=w_2(V)+w_2(W)$.  It follows that $A$ is a subgroup of $H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$.
2. If $a,b\in H^1(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)=\text{Hom}(G,O(1))$ then there are essentially unique one-dimensional representations $L,M$ with $w_1(L)=a$ and $w_1(M)=b$, and this gives $w_2(L\oplus M)=ab$  It follows that $A$ contains all decomposable elements of $H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$.
3. There is also a well-known isomorphism $H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z})=\text{Hom}(G,S^1)=\text{Hom}(G,SO(2))$.  Using this, we see that if $c\in H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ can be lifted to $H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z})$, then it lies in $A$.
4. Let $P\colon H^2(X;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^m(X;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ be any natural cohomology operation that annihilates $A$ for all $G$.  Using point 2 we see that $P$ is zero when $X=B(C_2^2)=(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)^2=K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)^2$.  However, it is a standard fact that the obvious map $$H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,n);\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^*(B(C_2^n);\mathbb{Z}/2)$$
   is injective for all $n$.  It follows from this (taking $n=2$) that $P=0$.  This means that there are no primary cohomological tests that we can use to determine whether elements lie in $A$.

UPDATE:
As Mark Grant points out, one can also treat this as a problem in obstruction theory.  It is probably best to organise this in terms of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence
$$ \widetilde{H}^p(BG;kO^q) \Longrightarrow \widetilde{kO}^{p+q}(BG), $$
with differentials
$$ d_r\colon E_r^{pq} \to E_r^{p+r,q-r+1}. $$
It is a standard fact that 
\begin{align*}
  kO^* &= \mathbb{Z}[\eta,\mu,\lambda]/(2\eta,\eta^3,\eta\mu,\mu^2-4\lambda) \\
 &= \mathbb{Z}[\lambda]\oplus 
    \mathbb{Z}/2[\lambda]\eta \oplus
    \mathbb{Z}/2[\lambda]\eta^2\oplus
    \mathbb{Z}[\lambda]\mu 
\end{align*}
with $|\eta|=-1$ and $|\mu|=-4$ and $|\lambda|=-8$.  (In particular, these degrees are all negative, corresponding to the fact that $kO$ is a connective spectrum, so the spectral sequence is concentrated in the fourth quadrant.) A class $c\in H^2(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ gives a class $c\eta^2\in E_2^{2,-2}$.  Because we are using the reduced homology version of the spectral sequence we see that $E_r^{pq}=0$ for $p\leq 0$ so all differentials ending at $E_r^{2,-2}$ are zero.  The problem is really to understand whether the elements $d_r(c\eta^2)$ are zero or not.  Because $kO^{-3}=0$, the first possible differential is $d_3(c\eta^2)\in H^5(BG;\mathbb{Z}).\mu$.  The result of Teichner mentioned by Mark must mean that this is
$$ d_3(c\eta^2) = \beta Sq^2(c) \mu. $$
As $kO^{-5}=kO^{-6}=kO^{-7}=0$, the next possible differential is $d_7(c\eta^2)$, which lies in $E_7^{9,-8}$, which is a subquotient of $H^9(BG;\mathbb{Z}).\lambda$.  One would need quite a bit of detailed information to determine which subquotient.  In general we have differentials $d_r(c\eta^2)\in E_r^{2+r,-1-r}$ for $r\in\{3,7,8,9\}\pmod{8}$.

For any particular group $G$ it is probably more efficient to just work out the representation theory and calculate the Stiefel-Whitney classes, but the spectral sequence approach sheds some interesting light on the general picture.

Answer (score 5):

You can set this up as an obstruction theory problem. Your cohomology class is represented by a map $c: BG\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$, and the question is whether this map lifts through the universal Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2:BO\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$.

The primary obstruction to such a lift turns out to be the class $$\beta Sq^2(c) = \beta(c\cup c)\in H^5(BG;\mathbb{Z}),$$ where $\beta$ is the Bockstein associated to the coefficient sequence $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2$. This and several other relevant facts can be found in

*Teichner, Peter*, [**6-dimensional manifolds without totally algebraic homology**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2160595), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 123, No.9, 2909-2914 (1995). [ZBL0858.57033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0858.57033).

As Neil Strickland mentions, there are higher obstructions which can possibly be defined in terms of secondary cohomology operations, provided you know enough about the Postnikov tower of $BO$.

Comment: Let me point out that there are infinitely many potentially nontrivial obstructions since the cohomological dimension of the group $G$ is not finite.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a general criterion, but here are two relevant references.

1) Several statements concerning the relation between the cohomology ring and the subring of Stiefel-Whitney classes are discussed in:

- P. Guillot. The computation of Stiefel-Whitney classes. 
  Annales de l'institut Fourier, Volume 60 (2010) no. 2 , p. 565-606.

The  basic punchline seems to be that for most groups, the cohomology ring is generated by Stiefel-Whitney classes of real representations.

2) There is also

- J. Gunarwardena, B. Kahn and C.B. Thomas. Stiefel-Whitney classes of real representations of finite groups. J. Algebra 126 (1989), 327-347.

This paper contains some example calculations. In particular, on pp. 337-338, there is an explicit example group where $H^2$ is not generated by Stiefel-Whitney classes of real representations.

There are some further papers, by Gunarwardena, Kahn, (and probably more that I'm not aware of right now) computing Stiefel-Whitney classes of the regular representation. But again, I don't know of a general criterion. Probably, if you have a specific group, not too large, the methods in the above papers might help deciding the question if all of $H^2$ is generated by Stiefel-Whitney classes.